# Select statement use Microsoft.Azure.Documents

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a project using CosmosDb and Microsoft Azure Document library with c#.

I want to execute a stored procedure that retrieve all the record of a contsiner but the code retrieve only 100 record.

The code is the following :

```
            string collectionToUse;
            string partition;
            if (typeof(T).ToString().IndexOf("Telemetry") != -1)
            {

    DocumentDBRepository<EBB.Web.Telemerty.Models.Telemetry>.Initialize();
            collectionToUse = AppSettings.collection;
            partition = "id";
            }
            else
            {

    DocumentDBRepository<EBB.Web.Telemerty.Models.Events>.Initialize();
            collectionToUse = AppSettings.collection2;
            partition = "uid";
           }

           Uri uri = 
           UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri(AppSettings.database, collectionToUse, AppSettings.spName);


           RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partition) };
           var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(uri, options, null);

           List<T> list = new  List<T>();
           list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(result.Response);

           return list;
```

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance for help me.
Simone

Answer (score 0):

In Cosmos DB stored procedures cannot return all the documents in the container because the scope of the stored procedure execution isn't the full container but rather ONLY the logical partition that you specify in the `RequestOptions`. This means that your SP will only return documents that have this logical partition value in their properties.